# Erro ao exibir uma coleção de telefones e emails de um contato

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa

Quero exibir em uma página XHTML (JSF+PrimeFaces) uma lista de contatos com telefones e e-mails.

Consigo exibir tudo que eu quero em uma classe de teste:

```
package com.fercosmig.testes;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import com.fercosmig.contato.model.Contato;
import com.fercosmig.contato.model.Email;
import com.fercosmig.contato.model.Telefone;
import com.fercosmig.contato.repository.ContatoRepository;
import com.fercosmig.util.jpa.JpaUtil;

public class TesteListaContatos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManager manager = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

        ContatoRepository contatos = new ContatoRepository(manager);

        List<Contato> contatosLista = contatos.todos();

        for (Contato contato : contatosLista){
            System.out.print(contato.getId());
            System.out.print(" - ");
            System.out.print(contato.getNome());
            System.out.print(" - ");
            System.out.println(contato.getObservacao());

            for (Telefone telefone : contato.getTelefones()){
                System.out.print(telefone.getDdd());
                System.out.print(" - ");
                System.out.print(telefone.getNumero());
                System.out.print(" - ");
                System.out.print(telefone.getRamal());
                System.out.print(" - ");
                System.out.print(telefone.getTipo());
                System.out.print(" - ");
                System.out.println(telefone.getOperadora());
            }
            for (Email email : contato.getEmails()){
                System.out.print(email.getEmail());
                System.out.print(" - ");
                System.out.println(email.getTipo());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado desta classe de teste na console é:

```
1 - Alfredo Neves - colega da faculdade
11 - 955555555 - null - CELULAR - VIVO
11 - 12341234 - null - COMERCIAL - null
11 - 23452345 - null - RESIDENCIAL - null
alfredo@gmail.com - PARTICULAR
2 - Rodolfo Complefica - colega de trabalho
11 - 956785678 - null - CELULAR - TIM
11 - 89078907 - null - RESIDENCIAL - null
rodolfo@gmail.com - PARTICULAR
```

Quero colocar isto ná página

```xml
<h:form id="frm1">
    <h:dataTable value="#{consultaContatoBean.contatos}" var="contato"
        border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Id" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{contato.id}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Nome" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{contato.nome}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Observação" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{contato.observacao}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Telefones" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:panelGroup>

                <ui:repeat var="telefone" value="#{contato.telefones}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{telefone}" />
                </ui:repeat>

            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Emails" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:panelGroup>

                <ui:repeat var="email" value="#{contato.emails}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{email}" />
                </ui:repeat>

            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

mas apresenta o erro abaixo:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.fercosmig.contato.model.Contato.telefones, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

O erro está na estrutura de repetição que mostra todos os números de telefone e todos os e-mails.

Alguém tem alguma ideia para resolver este problema?

Comment: É uma lazy `LazyInitializationException`, então duas formas de resolver: altere o *fetch* da lista de telefones do contato para *EAGER*; e a mais "elegante", fazer um filtro (ou use um pronto) que inicialize a sessão.

Comment: obrigado, vou tentar alterar o fetch.

Comment: OK, se der certo avise que incluo uma resposta para você considerando as duas abordagens.

Comment: opa, eu estava usando duas classes @ Embeddable para os telefones e e-mails. E na hora do select o hibernate não fazia o Join. Acabei trocando as duas para @ Entity mapeadas com  @ ManyToOne e coloquei o fetch como EAGER. Tenho certeza que tem um jeito de fazer com objeto de coleções (@ Embeddable). Mas deixa para lá. Já está funcionando. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @fercosmig, por favor, não coloque `EAGER` no relacionamento entre Contato e Telefone, a não ser que você queira **sempre** que os telefones venham toda vez que você consultar por qualquer contato no seu sistema. Em geral, isto é uma má ideia. Opte por fazer uma consulta pontual (com HQL ou Criteria) aos contatos usando `join fetch` para pegar os telefones.

Comment: Se eu descobrir como fazer usando a coleção anotada como @ Embeddable, vou alterar o sistema. É um sistema de agenda, ele mostra o contato, os telefones e os e-mails, sempre.